# Почему поведение конвейерной функции при выводе результата не отличается от нормальной табличной функции?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Создал конвейерную функцию, и другую, не конвейерную функцию. Но обе функции при вызове в запросе отображают результат только после полного выполнения.

Почему конвейерная функция не возвращает каждую запись, как только данные для неё становятся доступными?

Вот код функций:

```
create or replace type tfrow as object (cnt number, description varchar2(50));
/
create or replace type tftab as table of tfrow;
/
create or replace function gettab(cnt int, sec int) return tftab as
    t tftab := tftab();
begin
    for i in 1..cnt loop
        dbms_session.sleep(sec);
        t.extend;
        t(t.last) := tfrow(i,'row #'||i);
    end loop;
    return t;
end;
/    
create or replace function gettabp(cnt int, sec int) return tftab pipelined as
begin
    for i in 1..cnt loop
        dbms_session.sleep(sec);
        pipe row(tfrow(i,'piped row #'||i));
    end loop;
    return;
end;
/
```

Вот так их вызываю:

```
--TF call
select * from table (gettab (10, 1));
--pipelined TF call
select * from table (gettabp(10, 1));
```

Поведение обоих не отличается, каждый запрос через 10 сек. выводит 10 записей.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle Pipelined function working like normal function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65011129) от участника [@gunaseelan thirumal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6726060/gunaseelan-thirumal)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65011129

Answer (score 4):

Конвейерная функция работает корректно, но с целью оптимизации производительности размер выборки в клиенте извлекает N строк, прежде чем вернет вообще что-либо. N зависит от клиента и устанавливается в каждом клиенте по разному.

Чтобы сразу увидеть в выводе возвращаемые отдельные строки, надо отключить (или уменьшить) размер выборки.

В SQL*Plus это достигается командой `set arraysize 1` (по умолчанию установлено 15). На самом деле, будет выводится не одна, а *две* строки за раз, по причине того, что SQL*Plus выбирает дополнительно одну строку в т.н. *prefetch*, который нельзя отключить. Чтобы увидеть, когда действительно записи стали доступны, можно создать простую  функцию, которая в запросе вернёт штамп времени для каждой записи результата:

```
create or replace function getts return varchar2 is
begin 
    return to_char (systimestamp, 'mi:ss.ff3');
end;
/
```

Результат конвейерной функции будет выводится пакетами по 2 записи за раз:

```
SQL> set arrays 1
SQL> select t.*, getts ts from table (gettabp(9, 1)) t
/
       CNT DESCRIPTION  TS
---------- ------------ ------------
         1 piped row #1 44:23.018
         2 piped row #2 44:24.072
         3 piped row #3 44:25.096
         [...]
         8 piped row #8 44:30.216
         9 piped row #9 44:31.240

9 rows selected.
```

Результат нормальной табличной функции будет доступрен через ~9 сек. и все 9 записей будут выведены за раз:

```
SQL> select t.*, getts ts from table (gettab (9, 1)) t

       CNT DESCRIPTION  TS
---------- ------------ ------------
         1 row #1       49:40.681
         2 row #2       49:40.688
         3 row #3       49:40.688
         [...]
         8 row #8       49:40.718
         9 row #9       49:40.718

9 rows selected.
```